# Xamarin Forms Push Notifications using Azure Messaging Hub not working in release mode

Tags: c#, azure, xamarin.forms, push-notification, xamarin.android

I added a functionality to my Xamarin Forms App allowing it to receive Notifications from Azure.
Everything works fine in debug mode, but in release mode, the App crashes when I receive a notification.

I got a logger working with Adb to see the exception. The code I am using is the following:

```
public void OnPushNotificationReceived(Context context, INotificationMessage message)
    {
        try
        {
            var msgData = message.Data;

            if (msgData.ContainsKey("EventType"))
            {
                try
                {
                    if (AllowStoreNotification(msgData["VirtualStoreId"], msgData["EventType"]))
                    {
                        SendNotification(message.Title, message.Body);
                    }
                }
                catch (KeyNotFoundException ex)
                {
                    new TrackEvent("Could not deliver notification. Parameter error.")
                        .AddParameter("exception", ex.Message.ToString())
                        .Send();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Error("Notification", ex.Message);
        }

        void SendNotification(string title, string body)
        {
            var notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "PushNotifications")
                           .SetContentTitle(title)
                           .SetContentText(body)
                           .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.logo_pink_circle)
                           .SetAutoCancel(true)
                           .SetDefaults((int)NotificationDefaults.All)
                           .SetPriority((int)NotificationPriority.High)
                           .Build();

            if (_notificationManager is null)
            {
                NotificationManagerCompat.From(context).Notify(0, notification);
            }
            else
            {
                _notificationManager.Notify(0, notification);
            }
        }
    }
```

The _notificationManager is null for version `Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.O`.

The exception from de ADB log `adb logcat Notification:E *:S`:

```
Notification: no non-static method "Lcom/microsoft/windowsazure/messaging/notificationhubs/BasicNotificationMessage;.getData()Ljava/util/Map;"
```

Anyone knows how to fix this?

Comment: What is your Xamarin.Forms version?  And you need to add Notification channels in API 26 according to [notification channel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/notifications/local-notifications#creating-a-notification-channel), I test my code at Debug and Release mode, it all works fine.

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT, I'm using latest Xamarin Forms version 5.0.0.2012. Also using latest version of Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging 121.1.0. When debugging I get the notification with no problem, when in release it crashes the App on any action I do over INotificationMessage message (except testing if it's null, which it isn't)

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to make it work using the skip linking assembly.
[image: AndroidProject]

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the certificate you uploaded to azure, it's just for development, not for production
You have a few options:

- Change the certificate once you move to production
- 2 clouds, one for development and another for production.
- Or just compile your app as production every time you want to test notifications

Comment: Hi Isaac. It don't remember of uploading any certificate. I used a FCM key on Azure and created a NotificationHub. I can also receive a notification in release mode, with success, in my Xamarin.Forms App if it just logs something, for instance.